# Simpler code to generate multiple plots in R based on column values?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, row

my sample dataframe `df` is as follows

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
              var1 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
              var2 = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001),
              var3 = c(1:8))
```

Which results in

```
  ID var1 var2 var3
1  1    a 2000    1
2  1    a 2001    2
3  2    a 2000    3
4  2    a 2001    4
5  3    b 2000    5
6  3    b 2001    6
7  4    b 2000    7
8  4    b 2001    8
```

My goal is to plot `var2` by `var3` in a line graph using `ggplot2`, but I want a separate plot for each unique `ID` value.  So far, I have been able to do this by subsetting `df` by unique `ID` values, then plotting the variables.  For example, I have this code

```
df1<- subset(df1, df1$ID == 1)
ggplot(df2, aes(var2, var3)) +
       geom_line() +
       geom_point()
```

Which produces the following plot

[image: plot1]

This works fine, but uses a lot of code and I have dozens of `ID` values in my real dataset so I would like to be able to do this quicker and more efficiently.  Is there a way I can do this using a loop or a function?  I am still new to R and am stumped.  Thank you.

Comment: `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()` from `ggplot2` an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with `facet_wrap`, but that will put all your plots on one page, which won't work if you have lots of IDs. Instead, you could create all your plots and store them in a list:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4),
              var1 = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'),
              var2 = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001),
              var3 = c(1:8))

plot_list <- lapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x)
{
  ggplot(x, aes(var2, var3)) +
         geom_line() +
         geom_point()
})
```

Now you can plot them as easily as:

```
plot_list[[1]]
```

[image]

```r
plot_list[[2]]
```

[image]

```r
plot_list[[3]]
```

[image]

```r
plot_list[[4]]
```

[image]

Or you can save them to file with a simple loop:

```
for(i in seq_along(plot_list)) ggsave(paste0("plot_", i, ".png"), plot_list[[i]])
```

Which will save all four plots as files named "plot_1.png" to "plot_4.png" in your working directory.

<sup>Created on 2020-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>